# Laravel telegram bot sdk

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Есть вопрос: делаю телеграм бота на заказ, на laravel, использую laravel sdk ^2.0 (irazasyed автор)пакет, поднял серв с самописным сертификатом, делал всё по туториалам, говорят нада настроить веб хук по сылке в адресной строке  https://api.telegram.org/bot<мой токен с botfather>/setWebhook?url=<Домен + сылка, которая прописаная в роутах>, на что мне приходит json ответ: Webhook was set, в контроллере код следующий:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function webhook(Request $request){
        $key = env('TELEGRAM_TOKEN', 'мой токен');

        $telegram = new Api($key);

        $result = $telegram->getWebhookUpdate();

        $text       = isset($result["message"]["text"]) ? $result["message"]["text"] : "";
        $chat_id    = isset($result["message"]["chat"]["id"]) ? $result["message"]["chat"]["id"] : 0;
        $username   = isset($result["message"]["from"]["username"]) ? $result["message"]["from"]["username"] : "";

        $telegram->sendMessage([
            'chat_id'       => <мой чат id>,
            'text'          => $text
        ]);
        
    }
    
}
```

роуты:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'webhook/telegram', [
    'uses' => 'TelegramController@webhook'
]);
```

Проверял в постмане, если в ручную кинуть запрос на отправку меседжа, то всё ок, но если отправить меседж боту, то реакции 0, потому я думаю что проблема где-то меджу серваком и ботом(ерорных записей в логах laravel и сервака не было), всмысле запрос от бота идёт ок, но не идёт ко мне на серв, а если и идёт, то не в метод, пробовал так же продебажить, приходит ли туда вообше что то, результат отрицательный.
Прошу помощи с этим вопросом, перепробовал всё.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

1. В библиотеке irazasyed есть команда [`php artisan telegram:webhook`](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/439552ebbbbbb9051f435c6556bb1c2ba5771425/src/Laravel/Artisan/WebhookCommand.php#L13), используя ее можно легче управлять вебхуком напрямую из вашего приложения
2. Для вебхука необходим только тип запроса POST, в роутах нет необходимости создавать get-запрос для этого.
3. Вероятнее всего проблема в том, что у вас используется самоподписный сертификат. Что бы он работал с Telegram API, необходимо отправлять файл с публичным ключем вместе с `setWebhook` методом. В случае если вы будете использовать `telegram:webhook` команду, то нужно указать параметр `certificate_path` в конфигурации вашего бота (`config/telegram.php`), в котором указать путь к файлу с публичным ключем.

К сожалению библиотека irazasyed ужасно документирована и имеет много проблем в коде, поэтому довольно не комфортна для пользователей, которые не копаются в ней напрямую. Именно по этой причине я написал собственную библиотеку и делал упор на документацию и примеры [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot), если вы еще не сильно интегрировались с библиотекой irazasyed, то вам будет комфортнее ознакомиться с моей библиотекой.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, в будущем обязательно им воспользуюсь, однако конкретно в этом случае пересел на питон, за недостатком времени перед дедлайном, еще раз спасибо за ответ))

Comment: Добрый день, вот какую ошибку выдает во время require пакета
 ` return new TeleBotObjectException('You should specify at least 1 bot to use BotManager'); `